# Entity Framework - Include in sub query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, include

I'm not sure if this has been answered yet, I looked at a couple of questions but I don't think they were quite what I was after.

Let's say I have 3 tables:

```
Restaurant 1.....M MenuCategory 1.....M MenuItem
```

I have a L2E query that looks something like this:

```
Restaurant = context.Restaurant
   .Include(r => r.MenuCategory)
   .FirstOrDefault(r => r.RestaurantId == resaurantId);
```

Which works to some extent, but it only pre-loads the menu categories.

As a work around I am able to iterate around each category and call .Load() on them, but this will involve hitting a lot more that in theory I should need to.

What I really want to be able to do is something like:

```
Restaurant = context.Restaurant
   .Include(r => r.MenuCategory)
   .Include(r => r.MenuCategory.MenuItems)
   .FirstOrDefault(r => r.RestaurantId == resaurantId);
```

But clearly this isn't available as r.MenuCategory is an enumerable

ANSWER 1:

context.Restaurant.Include("MenuCategory.MenuItems");

- This works, but it is not strongly typed.  I wonder if anyone is able to come up with a second answer that is strongly typed (I may move this to another question as this has been answered, and answered well.

I have moved this to another question as I felt it was unfair to take away from an answer that is perfect and works exactly as it should:

[Entity Framework - Include in sub query? - Part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663783/entity-framework-include-in-sub-query-part-2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This link here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx) seems to resolve your problem ?

```
var result = context.Restaurant.Include("MenuCategory.MenuItems");
```

Comment: Well done - this sorted the issue for me....but, I really don't like this untyped approach, which is why I'd used an extension method.  I will put the extension method in the question - just wonder if anyone is able to come up with a typed solution

Comment: I have setup a part 2 to this question here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663783/entity-framework-include-in-sub-query-part-2, if you're interested

Answer (score 7):

You can still use the Strongly typed version to do it. Just use:

```
    Restaurant = context.Restaurant
    .Include(r => r.MenuCategory.Select(m => m.MenuItems))
    .FirstOrDefault(r => r.RestaurantId == resaurantId);
```